# Is it possible to provide a few values for the same param in XSL (vararg)?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to create an XSL 2.0 template, which I would be able to call with a few `<xsl:with-param/>` values, all of them bound to the same `<xsl:param>`. In other words, I'm looking for a [variadic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) template or its best alternative. Can you suggest some?

ps. This is what I came up with:

```
<xsl:template name="i">
  <xsl:param name="args"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$args/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, I'm calling it like this:

```
<xsl:template match="f">
  <xsl:call-template name="i">
    <xsl:with-param name="args"/>
      <a><xsl:value-of select="./@one"/></a>
      <a><xsl:value-of select="./@two"/></a>
    </xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: An example would be useful. In general, you could send a CSV string as the param and use tokenize() to extract individual values. There are more options available  ib XSLT 3 .0 which supports maps and arrays. And of course, you can also send a sequence as the param.

Comment: You can't call a named template with two or more `with-param` elements with the same `@name`. But as Michael says, you can have a single `with-param` whose value is a sequence of more than one value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There are many ways to do this**, below are just three of them:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:param name="pParams" select="3,5,15,22,7"/>
 <xsl:param name="pParams2" select="'3,5,15,22,7'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pParams3" select="/*/*[1], /*/*[2], /*/*[3] "/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:for-each select="$pParams">
      <xsl:sequence select=". * 2"/>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($pParams2, ',')">
      <xsl:sequence select="number(.) * 2"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    
    <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'"/>
    
    <xsl:for-each select="$pParams3">
      <xsl:sequence select="name(.)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>
  <a/>
  <b/>
  <c/>
</t>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
6 10 30 44 14
6 10 30 44 14
a b c
```

Comment: This seems reasonable when params are data primitives, like integers. In my case, I have nodes as params.

Comment: @yegor256 See the updated answer. To summarize, you can pass any sequence as a parameter. In XSLT 3.0 one can also pass an array (this is an XPath 3.1 - only datatype) as a parameter.

Comment: This will work well for absolute XPath expressions. I can't figure out how can this work for relative ones.

Comment: I'm struggling to see where your difficulty lies...