# How to pass a collection of nodes as a param of an XSL template?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

This is my template (a simplification of a real situation):

```
<xsl:template name="i">
  <xsl:param name="args"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$args/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I call it like this:

```
<xsl:template match="f">
  <xsl:call-template name="i">
    <xsl:with-param name="args"/>
      <a><xsl:value-of select="./@one"/></a>
      <a><xsl:value-of select="./@two"/></a>
    </xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

Basically, I create artificial nodes `<a/>`, which looks ugly to me. Is there a better way?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to pass in, if you use `xsl:value-of select="..."/>`, you are creating text nodes with the string value of the `select` expression, therefore a template doing e.g. `$args/*` which selects element nodes wouldn't make sense. I suspect you want to pass the "long xpath" and the "another long xpath" selected (element?) nodes, I would use `<xsl:with-param name="args" select="long xpath, another long xpath"/>`, but you then get a sequence of element nodes you would need to process  as e.g. `<xsl:for-each select="$args">..</xsl:for-each>`, not as `select="$args/*"`.

Comment: It would be better to clarify your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73285503/is-it-possible-to-provide-a-few-values-for-the-same-param-in-xsl-vararg instead of posting a new one.

Comment: @MartinHonnen one example of my "long xpath" is `foo:my_function(.)`. Thus, it's not really a simple XPath, it could be a complex expression with functions and references to the nodes available in the context where I call the template only.

Comment: What does that function return, a sequence of element nodes, a sequence of document nodes, a mixed sequence of nodes and atomic values? It is not clear which types of values you are working with by giving the name of a function and which types you want to process if you use `xsl:value-of` on them, as that creates a text node.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by creating those `<a>` elements? Please provide a minimal, reproducible example, including your desired output, so we can see what you are trying to achieve. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I would think that e.g. Michael Kay's book has a section on parameters and variables, there types and values that is a better read than the spec, but as for the spec, read https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#variables-and-parameters, https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#default-values-of-parameters, https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#variable-values, https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#temporary-trees

Comment: @ConalTuohy I updated the question, now it's fully reproducible, I believe

Comment: Still not clear why you create `a` elements with the value of attribute nodes or what you want to achieve; as I suggested, doing e.g. `<xsl:with-param name="args" select="@one, @two"/>` is possible, then your template could process `xsl:for-each select="$args"` to deal with attribute nodes or perhaps just do `<xsl:value-of select="$args"/>` if you just want to output the string values of the passed in `$args`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen can you please post a working example, doing exactly what my code is doing, but without `<a/>`? I will be glad to accept it.

Comment: @yegor256 your question is still vague because you don't provide either a sample input or a desired output. Also, you have just two templates with no stylesheet to contain them; a reproducible example is something which someone else can run without having to write any code themselves.

Comment: I think you are fighting to understand that the value of the `<xsl:with-param>` `select` attribute can be **any** sequence. Thus you can just have: `<xsl:with-param name="yourName" select="@one, @two"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My example would use functions but I have done both:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:function name="mf:f1" as="text()">
    <xsl:param name="items" as="item()*"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$items"/>
  </xsl:function>
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="foo">
    <function-example>
      <xsl:sequence select="mf:f1((@one, @two))"/>
    </function-example>
    
    <template-example1>
      <xsl:call-template name="h">
        <xsl:with-param name="args" select="@one, @two"/>
      </xsl:call-template>      
    </template-example1>    
    
    <template-example2>
      <xsl:call-template name="i">
        <xsl:with-param name="args" select="@one, @two"/>
      </xsl:call-template>      
    </template-example2>
  </xsl:template>
  

  <xsl:template name="h">
    <xsl:param name="args"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$args"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template name="i">
    <xsl:param name="args"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$args">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

transforms

```
<foo one="1" two="2"/>
```

into

```
<function-example>1 2</function-example>
<template-example1>1 2</template-example1>
<template-example2>12</template-example2>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyfAiD9

Of course, for the sole `xsl:value-of` use, if you don't want to have the default space separator between the args values, use `xsl:value-of separator=""`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following **simple** example:

**XML**

```
<f one="alpha" two="bravo"/>
```

**template call**

```
<xsl:template match="f">
    <xsl:call-template name="i">
        <xsl:with-param name="args" select="@one, @two"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

**template execution**

```
<xsl:template name="i">
    <xsl:param name="args"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$args">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93PXKr2

Comment: What if I one of my arguments is more complex than just a simple XPath `@one`? For example, it is calculated using `<xsl:choose>`.

Comment: @yegor256, first of all, there is XPath base `if (condition) then expression1 else expression2` so it is doubtful you need to use `xsl:choose/xsl:when` and can't just just `<xsl:with-param name="args" select="if (..) then .. else if (..) then .. else .."/>`. But for the general question, I pointed you to the links explaining the type and values of params and variables and how the `as` attribute plays a crucial role.

Comment: So doing e.g. `<xsl:with-param name="args" as="attribute()*"><xsl:choose><xsl:when test=".."><xsl:sequence select="@one"/></xsl:when><xsl:otherwise><xsl:sequence select="@two"/></xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose></xsl:with-param>` is possible.

Comment: @yegor256 I don't know the answer to your question. If you post a [mcve], I will think about it. In general, there are many ways in XSLT to construct a *sequence*.